# Filtering the result of a Query in flask SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I am working on a query that depends on the result of another query. **Here's my question**: Is it possible to filter a query using the result of another query?

I have two tables that I would like to query by joining them. I tried this query:

```
# Get all data for a particular country
de_market= db.session.query(
    func.count(certificate.id),
    func.month(certificate.creation_time).label('month'),
    func.year(certificate.creation_time).label('year')).join(B2cCustomer.certificates).group_by(func.month(certificate.creation_time),
    func.year(certificate.creation_time))
    .filter(certificate.report_sent != None)
    .filter(B2cCustomer.market == market_code)
    .all()
```

so after the result I want to then filter the result again:

```
# filter the country data by the different msm campaign
get_data_based_on_msm = de_market.filter(certifcate.msm == msm).all()
```

I did this but didn't get a good result. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Hello Dave. Can you add additional information to the bottom of your question? Showing the model of both the "certificate" and "B2cCustomer" tables (all tables involved)?

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to filter a query using the result of another query?

Yes.

Well, kind of.

You wrote:

```
de_market = db.session.query(
    ...
    .filter(certificate.report_sent != None)
    .filter(B2cCustomer.market == market_code)
    .all()

# and then expressed an interest in
de_market.filter(certificate.msm == msm).all()
```

That is to say, we assign `q = ... .filter(cond1).filter(cond2)`
and later we are interested in `q.filter(cond3)`.

Can you do that? Yes.
Now, here is the fly in the ointment.
You finished up with retrieving the result rows using `.all()`.
My advice is to not do that.

Clone the query,
write a helper function that returns such a query,
do what you must to make an **un-executed** query available.

With that in hand, yes, you can easily tack on extra filters.
Here is some idiomatic usage:

```
        q = ... .filter(cond1).filter(cond2)
        if cond3:
            q = q.filter(cond3)
        if limit:
            q = q.limit(limit)
        return q
```

But as soon as you ask for results using `.all()`,
all bets are off, you don't get to modify the query after that.